# JodaTime unable to normalize PeriodType

Tags: java, android, date, jodatime, period

So I have 2 date pickers for a start and end time, which give back a DateTime.

I need to calculate the duration between these two times in the format of "hours hr mins hr", so for example, "1 hr 30 mins".
If there is a day difference, it will display  "24 hr", so we use hours instead of days.

The problem I am having is that whatever way I got this working, it breaks if the user selects a month ahead. They never should choose a month ahead but are given the option to.

I get this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to normalize as PeriodType is missing either years or months but period has a month/year amount: P1M3W6DT1H
        at org.joda.time.Period.normalizedStandard(Period.java:1640)
```

And my code is:

```
Period durationHoursAndMinutes =  new Period(startDate.toLocalDateTime(), endDate.toLocalDateTime()).normalizedStandard(PeriodType.time());
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
  .appendHours()
  .appendSuffix(getResources().getString(R.string.mytrips_tripview_rail_waitTime_hr))
  .appendSeparator(" ")
  .appendMinutes()
  .appendSuffix(getResources().getString(R.string.mytrips_tripview_rail_waitTime_min))
.toFormatter();

if(durationHoursAndMinutes.getMinutes() > 0){
  return formatter.print(durationHoursAndMinutes);
}else {
  return null;
}
```

I looked at the code for the PeriodType and it says to throw the exception if the months != 0, which it won't be. Just wondering if there is a way I can solve this.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you give a short but complete example demonstrating the problem? (You probably don't need your formatter - and it almost certainly doesn't need to be on Android. A tiny console app demonstrating the problem would make this a lot clearer.)

Comment: Note that your claim that months won't be != 0 is clearly wrong given the reported failing period: P1M3W6DT1H

Comment: @JonSkeet I just saw in the code it said something about throwing the exception if months != 0

Comment: Indeed. And in your case, months == 1 - that's what the "1M" in "P1M3W6DT1H" means. That period is 1 month, 3 weeks, 6 days and 1 hour.

Comment: @JonSkeet so that's why its crashing right? that's what i meant above by it wont be 0

Comment: Oh, that was a confusing way of putting it then. I thought you meant "the condition wouldn't be satisfied, i.e. months really *will* be 0". Anyway, I've given a solution - it would still be helpful if you'd show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah sorry my bad. Yep your solution worked great. I will try do up a short program in a while, in work at the moment so don't really have time right now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *suspect* the simplest way to do this is just to pass the `PeriodType` into the constructor instead:

```
new Period(
    startDate.toLocalDateTime(),
    endDate.toLocalDateTime(),
    PeriodType.time());
```

Then you don't need to perform any other normalization.

Comment: Great that worked! Thanks for the solution, I used the normalization because I saw it on another stack overflow solution.